# "error: implicit declaration of function ‘vfs_readlink’" while installing VMware Tools

Tags: fedora, compiling, vmware

Been trying to reinstall vmware tools for my Fedora 20 VMware Fusion 6.0.4  Box for some time on my OSX Mavericks host now. After the Fedora update it was necessary so I could access Drop Box from the host and easily resize the window.

But now I keep on getting these errors and retrying after installing all does not seem to work. See here the final part with warnings and errors causing this failure:

```
make
gcc
kernel headers of the running kernel


Searching for GCC...
Detected GCC binary at "/bin/gcc".
The path "/bin/gcc" appears to be a valid path to the gcc binary.
Would you like to change it? [no] 

Searching for a valid kernel header path...
Detected the kernel headers at 
"/lib/modules/3.15.5-200.fc20.i686/build/include".
The path "/lib/modules/3.15.5-200.fc20.i686/build/include" appears to be a 
valid path to the 3.15.5-200.fc20.i686 kernel headers.
Would you like to change it? [no] 

Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only'
/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.15.5-200.fc20.i686/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.15.5-200.fc20.i686'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/message.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/backdoor.h:30:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/message.c:54:
/tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/./shared/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined [enabled by default]
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)
 ^
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/./shared/kernelStubs.h:36,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/message.c:45:
include/linux/printk.h:92:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "
 ^
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/dir.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/hgfs.h:40:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/hgfsProto.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/dir.c:37:
/tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/./shared/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined [enabled by default]
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)
 ^
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/3.15.5-200.fc20.i686/arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:44,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/3.15.5-200.fc20.i686/arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:5,
                 from include/linux/preempt.h:18,
                 from include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/dir.c:29:
include/linux/printk.h:92:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "
 ^
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/rpcout.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/./shared/vmware.h:39:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/rpcout.c:43:
/tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/./shared/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined [enabled by default]
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)
 ^
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/./shared/kernelStubs.h:36,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/rpcout.c:33:
include/linux/printk.h:92:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "
 ^
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/hgfsUtil.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/hgfs.h:40:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/hgfsUtil.h:55,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/hgfsUtil.c:33:
/tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/./shared/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined [enabled by default]
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)
 ^
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/3.15.5-200.fc20.i686/arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:44,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/3.15.5-200.fc20.i686/arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:5,
                 from include/linux/preempt.h:18,
                 from include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/hgfsUtil.h:32,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/hgfsUtil.c:33:
include/linux/printk.h:92:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "
 ^
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/cpName.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/link.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/hgfs.h:40:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/hgfsProto.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/module.h:39,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/link.c:32:
/tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/./shared/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined [enabled by default]
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)
 ^
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/3.15.5-200.fc20.i686/arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:44,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/3.15.5-200.fc20.i686/arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:5,
                 from include/linux/preempt.h:18,
                 from include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from include/linux/wait.h:8,
                 from include/linux/fs.h:6,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/./shared/compat_fs.h:22,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/link.c:29:
include/linux/printk.h:92:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "
 ^
/tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/link.c: In function ‘HgfsReadlink’:
/tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/link.c:186:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘vfs_readlink’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
          error = vfs_readlink(dentry, buffer, buflen, fileName);
          ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only/link.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.15.5-200.fc20.i686'
make: *** [vmhgfs.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-F7dG4u/vmhgfs-only'

The filesystem driver (vmhgfs module) is used only for the shared folder 
feature. The rest of the software provided by VMware Tools is designed to work 
independently of this feature.

If you wish to have the shared folders feature, you can install the driver by 
running vmware-config-tools.pl again after making sure that gcc, binutils, make
and the kernel sources for your running kernel are installed on your machine. 
These packages are available on your distribution's installation CD.
```

I can finish the setup, but it does not really install things properly - shared folder is not mounted (folder is shown with no contents ) - and I also get this final warning

```
Found VMware Tools CDROM mounted at /run/media/jfrumau/VMware Tools. Ejecting 
device /dev/sr0 ...
/sbin/restorecon:  Warning no default label for /tmp/vmware-block-restore0/tmp_file
```

Any ideas around this issue - vmhgfs module related it seems -  so the shared folder gets mounted again and all works?

Comment: https://communities.vmware.com/message/2335864 might be related. Will read on it a bit later on.

Comment: Seems to be a patch for the error as stated in title of this question at https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=507664 . Seems one needs to modify vsock-only/linux/notify.c and add the four lines mentioned and patch three other files.

Comment: Adding multiple patches for VMWare Tools can be found here https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches . Only not for kernel 3.15 just yet. this error `vmhgfs-only/link.c:186:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘vfs_readlink’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]` is and issue with this script as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the patches listed [here](http://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=507664) you need to patch `link.c` from `vmhgfs.tar`.

```c
184a185
> #if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(3, 14, 99)
187a189,194
> #else
>          LOG(6, (KERN_DEBUG "VMware hgfs: HgfsReadlink: calling "
>                  "readlink_copy\n"));
>          error = readlink_copy(buffer, buflen, fileName);
> #endif
>       }
```

This worked for me.

Comment: As I never applied patches of this type I would love to know how to. Should I follow a guide like https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel as I seem to need to apply kernel patches? Two, can you recommend a tutorial to follow? Three, how long does it normally take for patches like these to be added to a regular upgrade so I do not have to do this , but just can do a `yum update` or `sudo fedora-upgrade` or using fedup?

Comment: Applying kernel patches is discussed here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/applying-patches.txt . Also, fedora is offering a kernel update now as well `kernel i686 3.15.6-200.fc20  updates 30 M` Does not seem to offer a fix for my issue though https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/kernel-3.15.6-200.fc20